# VSTS Click-once addin build error This operation requires an interactive window station. No on premise agent

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Hi guys i am trying to make a build for a VSTO click once addin on VSTS, however the requirements i had is that this should be machine independent therefor i cant use an on-premise agent.
the current build procces we have is quite complex and at some point calls and .exe which was a VB class to do some things on the publish folder. However when  i try to run it via powershell command on VSTS this error appears

```
##[error]start : This command cannot be run due to the error: TThis operation requires an interactive window station.
```

Is there a way (possible a poweshell script) to give enough admin rights run time on the hosted agent to lunch this .exe? i have tried passing in the --no-interactive flag and didn't help also i have tried removing any code from the VB class that has to do with console and rebuild the .exe still no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't control the hosted agent and can't run interactive applications on it. There is no way around it.

Either install a build agent somewhere (an Azure-hosted VM is always a good choice for this) or rewrite your interactive application's logic such that it's non-interactive. I'd recommend the latter.

Comment: Thanks for this info, will leave this question open for a couple more hours see if anyone knows of a way around else will mark this as correct.

Comment: @AvalothOath In my opinion, there isn't another better way.

Comment: Yup i think this was open long enough, thanks everyone.